# Transfer Files from one cloud storage to another

Tags: python, file-transfer, server-to-server

How to transfer files from one cloud storage to another. The files are CSV.

Where is the best place to start in relation to this problem?

For the time being the file just needs to transfer the files every week via manual execution. Eventually the files will be transferred on a scheduled basis.

Comment: have you tried scp command in python script using os module!

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start searching for this sites APIs. For example, [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python) has a very well documented API for python.

If you want to automate your script every X days/hours/etc, you can make use of `cron` if you are running Unix based systems.

Hope that helped.